# Excel process thread hiJacks KeyBoard strokes

Tags: vsto

We have a Developed a VSTO Add-In (Excel Add-In) Application with couple of Buttons in the Ribbon.

On Starting/launching the Application, It launches excel Instance. On the Button Click We are instantiating the WPF window having some Input Textboxes for the user to Enter the Values.

The Issue here is When we try to type in the Textboxes, It types it in the Excel window.

The Wpf window runs under the same process of the Add-In which is (Excel Process).

could you please suggest a solution foe this issue.

THANKS

Amol

Comment: show WPF Window as dialog

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest running a Windows form instead. Or you can try to place your WPF controls on the Windows form. Does it work as expected?